# How to get position id in custom list adapter?

Tags: android, listview

I try to make list. In this list each row will have 3 states:

1)Start state with Text and Button GET'

2)Upload state with progress bar and Button CANCEL

3)Ready state with Text and Button UPLOAD

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   // private ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Context context;
    private int[] laytypes;
    //private String[] list;


    public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> list,int[] laytypes,Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        //this.list2 = list2;
        this.context = context;
        this.laytypes=laytypes;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {


            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_firmware, null);

            TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_st1);

            listItemText.setText(list.get(position));

/*
            if(laytypes[position]==1)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_st1, null);


                ProgressBar DownloadBar;
                DownloadBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.downloadProgressBar);
                DownloadBar.setProgress(50 + laytypes[position]);
                DownloadBar.setMax(100);

            }
            else if(laytypes[position]==2)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_st2, null);

                TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string);

                listItemText.setText(list.get(position));

            }
            else
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_st3, null);

                TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string);

                listItemText.setText(list.get(position));
            }
*/

        }







        //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
        Button deleteBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
        deleteBtn.setTag(position);
        Button addBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
        addBtn.setTag(position);

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something

                list.remove(position); //or some other task
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something
                laytypes[position]=1;
                //list2.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

but for example on pushing delete Button - last row deletes instead of current (clicked row). How get current row id?

In my activity i have this code:

```
//TEST CUSTOM LIST CREATION
        //generate list
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("item1");
        list.add("item2");
        list.add("item3");
        list.add("item4");
        list.add("item5");
        list.add("item6");


        int[] laytypes = new int[50];
        laytypes[0]=0;
        laytypes[1]=0;
        laytypes[2]=0;
        laytypes[3]=0;
        laytypes[4]=0;
        laytypes[5]=0;
        laytypes[6]=0;


        //instantiate custom adapter
        MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(list,laytypes,this);

        //handle listview and assign adapter
        ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewTest);
        lView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
// private ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
private Context context;
private int[] laytypes;
//private String[] list;


public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> list,int[] laytypes,Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    //this.list2 = list2;
    this.context = context;
    this.laytypes=laytypes;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

//Your only mistake was View view = convertView; your list was removing the item but because of this line your view was not refreshing 
    View view = null;
    if (view == null) {


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_firmware, null);

        TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_st1);

        listItemText.setText(list.get(position));

/*
        if(laytypes[position]==1)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_st1, null);


            ProgressBar DownloadBar;
            DownloadBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.downloadProgressBar);
            DownloadBar.setProgress(50 + laytypes[position]);
            DownloadBar.setMax(100);

        }
        else if(laytypes[position]==2)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_st2, null);

            TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string);

            listItemText.setText(list.get(position));

        }
        else
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_st3, null);

            TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string);

            listItemText.setText(list.get(position));
        }
*/

    }







    //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
    Button deleteBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
    deleteBtn.setTag(position);
    Button addBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
    addBtn.setTag(position);

    deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something

            list.remove(position); //or some other task
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something
            laytypes[position]=1;
            //list2.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: Oh... thanks! but this do nothing on delate, and crahes on add)

Comment: Sorry for the first answer, I hope my edited answer will help you.

Comment: Just get it)) i ll try it... but i can't find difference with one of my samples...

Comment: it works!))) 

And one more question about "list". Can it contain more than one string in Row? And if it can, please give me a simple example)

Comment: @Dmitry Lyalin Please clarify your question...you mean to ask if you can have more than one textview in the row of listview or not right?

Comment: So i'm using array int[] laytypes Array to add some additional info.. Can i put all to my list?

Comment: You need to respective view in row item layout for any thing you need such as button or textview and please elaborate your requirements or design of the list you require to make.

Answer (score 0):

I have also done something like @drv, using tags, but it is more elegant to use the listview itself, if you ask me.

Here is an example from my own code (which I just wrote a couple of days ago) using a gridview, but it is basically the same thing (listview has the essential method). In my case I am using a fragment, so I pass it through a custom callback.

```
    mGridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
...
    mAdapter = new ImageWithTitleAdapter(getContext(), new ArrayList<Movie>());
    mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            ((Callback) getActivity())
                    .onItemSelected(v, position);
        }
    });
```

and later in the fragment:

```
/**
 * A callback interface that all activities containing this fragment must
 * implement. This mechanism allows activities to be notified of item
 * selections.
 */
public interface Callback {
    /**
     * DetailFragmentCallback for when an item has been selected.
     */
    void onItemSelected(View view, int pos);
}
```

Then in the activity, implementing the callback:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainFragment.Callback {
   /**
 * MainFragment Callback override - handles click events on gridview items
 * @param v - the calling view containing the data item
 * @param pos - the position of the view from the grid_view
 */
@Override
public void onItemSelected(View v, int pos) {
    Movie movie =  (Movie) v.getTag();
    // We are splitting the logic here because we don't just need to load the detail fragment
    // with the data. We also need to completely switch activities if it is single-pane
    if (LayoutUtil.twoPanes(this)) {
        loadDetailInTwoPane(pos, movie);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class)
                .putExtra(getString(R.string.key_grid_view_movie), movie)
                .putExtra(getString(R.string.key_grid_view_position), pos);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you... but it looks for me like  "Some Magic"... but i promise ill try to understand it!))